# Is there an option to put Names to have first letter capitalized?

Tags: cognito-forms

Was wondering whether there is an option to put the first letter on a name or even address as capital?

Answer (score 0):

We've definitely come across this requirement in the past, but this is the first time it has been requested by a Cognito Forms customer.  I have added this to our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/g7cg7dOW).  Please up-vote and comment on this feature to show your interest!